# Remove the "Advanced search" form on the result page?

Tags: 8, search

On Drupal 8, how can I remove the "Advanced search" form on the result page ?

I can hide it with css :

```
#edit-advanced,
#edit-help-link {
    display: none;
}
```

But I would prefer to do it with php or even better with a parameter in admin but I didn’t see any parameter related to Advanced search in

```
/ Administration / Configuration / Search and metadata
```

Comment: In older versions, there used to be a permission to access the form "use advanced search". Others would likely advise moving off to Search API instead of core search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go to:

```
admin/people/permissions
```

and uncheck the checkboxes for the users that don't need to use the Advanced Search.

[image]

Comment: I think it is the correct answer since this parameter do exactly what i need. But in my case it is already unchecked. Is there something else i should think of  ?

Comment: @SébastienGicquel if the user that you use is the admin (uid=1) this is the superuser and can see all in the site.

Comment: You're right : if I visit the website without being loggedin, i don’t see the advanced search.